# Graphics.drawRect not drawing rectangle fully?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create my own component for swing, but when i try to paint the border of it with drawRect, it only draws the left and top edges! Why is that, and how can it be fixed?
Here is  my paintComponent method:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

}
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please show the Class, that creates the JFrame...

Comment: @Andrew you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to create my own component for swing, but when i try to paint the border of it with drawRect,

Why are you trying to draw a Border. Swing supports borders. if your component needs a border then you should be using:

setBorder( new LineBorder(Color.RED) );

and let swing draw the border for you.

> it only draws the left and top edges!

I think you should be using:

```
g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you as a starting point:

```
package de.professional_webworkx.graphics;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawFrame extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1285962479945295143L;
    private JPanel northPanel;

    public DrawFrame() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Draw");
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(createNorthPanel(), BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        this.getContentPane().add(new DrawPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.setSize(1024, 768);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JPanel createNorthPanel() {

        northPanel = new JPanel();

        northPanel.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("XXXXXXXXXXXX");
        jLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        northPanel.add(jLabel);

        return northPanel;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DrawFrame();
    }
}
```

DrawPanel.class

```
package de.professional_webworkx.graphics;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4949248244138855737L;

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawRect(10, 10, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillRect(11, 11, getWidth()/2-1, getHeight()/2-1);

            g.draw3DRect(10, getHeight()/2+20, 600, 280, true);

        }


}
```

Patrick

UPDATE: Thanks to  camickr.

Comment: -1, it may be simple but it's not correct. First, custom painting is done by overriding paintComponent() and not paint() and secondly super.paintComponent(...) should be invoked at the start of the method.